# Problem getting my correct location with google chrome Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code which is responsible for the geographical location of latitude, longitude and the map of where one is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript-mobile-desktop-geolocation With No Simulation with Google Maps</title>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">      

<style>
body {font-family: Helvetica;font-size:11pt;padding:0px;margin:0px}
#title {background-color:#e22640;padding:5px;}
#current {font-size:10pt;padding:5px;}  
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialiseMap();initialise()">
<h1>location GPS</h1>
<div id="current">Initializing...</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:320px; height:350px"></div>

<script src="js/geoPosition.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script>
function initialiseMap()
{
    var myOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          mapTypeControl: true,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
          navigationControl: true,
          navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP      
        }   
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 }
 function initialise()
 {
    if(geoPosition.init())
    {
        document.getElementById('current').innerHTML="Receiving...";
        geoPosition.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,function(){document.getElementById('current').innerHTML="Couldn't get location"},{enableHighAccuracy:true});
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('current').innerHTML="Functionality not available";
    }
 }

 function showPosition(p)
 {
    var latitude = parseFloat( p.coords.latitude );
    var longitude = parseFloat( p.coords.longitude );
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML="latitude=" + latitude + " longitude=" + longitude;
    var pos=new google.maps.LatLng( latitude , longitude);
    map.setCenter(pos);
    map.setZoom(14);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<strong>yes</strong>"
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        title:"You are here"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

 }
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

the file geoPosition.js:

```
     var bb = { 
        success: 0,
        error: 0,
        blackberryTimeoutId : -1
     };

     function handleBlackBerryLocationTimeout()
     {
     if(bb.blackberryTimeoutId!=-1) {
        bb.error({ message:     "Timeout error", 
                   code:        3
               });
       }
     }
     function handleBlackBerryLocation()
     {
        clearTimeout(bb.blackberryTimeoutId);
        bb.blackberryTimeoutId=-1;
        if (bb.success && bb.error) {
                if(blackberry.location.latitude==0 && blackberry.location.longitude==0) {
                        //http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_unavailable_error
                        //POSITION_UNAVAILABLE (numeric value 2)
                        bb.error({message:"Position unavailable", code:2});
                }
                else
                {  
                        var timestamp=null;
                        //only available with 4.6 and later

  //http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/8861/blackberry_location_568404_11.jsp
                        if (blackberry.location.timestamp)
                        {
                                timestamp = new Date( blackberry.location.timestamp );
                        }
                        bb.success( { timestamp:    timestamp , 
                                      coords: { 
                                            latitude:  blackberry.location.latitude,
                                            longitude: blackberry.location.longitude
                                        }
                                    });
                }
                //since blackberry.location.removeLocationUpdate();
                //is not working as described http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/8861/blackberry_location_removeLocationUpdate_568409_11.jsp
                //the callback are set to null to indicate that the job is done

                bb.success = null;
                bb.error = null;
        }
     }

     var geoPosition=function() {

        var pub = {};
        var provider=null;
        var u="undefined";
        var ipGeolocationSrv = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=JSONPCallback';

        pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success,error,opts)
        {
                provider.getCurrentPosition(success, error,opts);
        }

        pub.jsonp = {
            callbackCounter: 0,

            fetch: function(url, callback) {
                var fn = 'JSONPCallback_' + this.callbackCounter++;
                window[fn] = this.evalJSONP(callback);
                url = url.replace('=JSONPCallback', '=' + fn);

                var scriptTag = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
                scriptTag.src = url;
                document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
            },

            evalJSONP: function(callback) {
                return function(data) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            }
        };

        pub.confirmation = function()
        {
            return confirm('This Webpage wants to track your physical location.\nDo you allow it?');
        };

        pub.init = function()
        {                                   
            try
            {
                var hasGeolocation = typeof(navigator.geolocation)!=u;
                if( !hasGeolocation ){
                    if( !pub.confirmation() ){
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                if ( ( typeof(geoPositionSimulator)!=u ) && (geoPositionSimulator.length > 0 ) ){
                        provider=geoPositionSimulator;
                } else if (typeof(bondi)!=u && typeof(bondi.geolocation)!=u  ) {
                        provider=bondi.geolocation;
                } else if ( hasGeolocation ) {
                        provider=navigator.geolocation;
                        pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, opts) 
     {
                                function _success(p) {
                                        //for mozilla geode,it returns the coordinates slightly differently
                                        var params;
                                        if(typeof(p.latitude)!=u) {
                                                params = {
                                                    timestamp: p.timestamp, 
                                                    coords: {
                                                        latitude:  p.latitude,
                                                        longitude: p.longitude
                                                    }
                                                };
                                        } else {
                                                params = p;
                                        }
                                        success( params );
                                }

     provider.getCurrentPosition(_success,error,opts);
                        }
                } else if(typeof(window.blackberry)!=u && blackberry.location.GPSSupported) {
                        // set to autonomous mode
                        if(typeof(blackberry.location.setAidMode)==u) {
                            return false;                                   
                        }
                        blackberry.location.setAidMode(2);
                        //override default method implementation
                        pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success,error,opts)
                        {
                                //passing over callbacks as parameter didn't work consistently
                                //in the onLocationUpdate method, thats why they have to be set outside
                                bb.success = success;
                                bb.error = error;
                                //function needs to be a string according to

     //http://www.tonybunce.com/2008/05/08/Blackberry-Browser-Amp-GPS.aspx
                                if(opts['timeout']) {
                                    bb.blackberryTimeoutId = setTimeout("handleBlackBerryLocationTimeout()",opts['timeout']);
                                } else {
                                    //default timeout when none is given to prevent a hanging script
                                    bb.blackberryTimeoutId = setTimeout("handleBlackBerryLocationTimeout()",60000);
                                }                                       

     blackberry.location.onLocationUpdate("handleBlackBerryLocation()");
                                blackberry.location.refreshLocation();
                        }
                        provider = blackberry.location;             

                } else if ( typeof(Mojo) !=u && typeof(Mojo.Service.Request)!="Mojo.Service.Request") {
                        provider = true;
                        pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, opts) 
    {
                            parameters = {};
                            if( opts ) {
                                 //http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1673#GPS-getCurrentPosition
                                 if (opts.enableHighAccuracy && opts.enableHighAccuracy == true ){
                                        parameters.accuracy = 1;
                                 }
                                 if ( opts.maximumAge ) {
                                        parameters.maximumAge = opts.maximumAge;
                                 }
                                 if (opts.responseTime) {
                                        if( opts.responseTime < 5 ) {
                                                parameters.responseTime = 1;
                                        } else if ( opts.responseTime < 20 ) {
                                                parameters.responseTime = 2;
                                        } else {
                                                parameters.timeout = 3;
                                        }
                                 }
                        }

                         r = new Mojo.Service.Request( 'palm://com.palm.location' , {
                                method:"getCurrentPosition",
                                    parameters:parameters,
                                    onSuccess: function( p ){
                                        success( { timestamp: p.timestamp, 
                                                   coords: {
                                                        latitude:  p.latitude, 
                                                        longitude: p.longitude,
                                                        heading:   p.heading
                                                    }
                                                });
                                    },
                                    onFailure: function( e ){
                                                        if (e.errorCode==1) {
                                                            error({ code:       3,
                                                                    message:    "Timeout"
                                                                });
                                                        } else if (e.errorCode==2){
                                                            error({ code:       2,
                                                                    message:    "Position unavailable" 
                                                                });
                                                        } else {
                                                            error({ code:       0,
                                                                    message:    "Unknown Error: webOS-code" + errorCode 
                                                                });
                                                        }
                                                }
                                    });
                        }

                }
                else if (typeof(device)!=u && typeof(device.getServiceObject)!=u) {
                        provider=device.getServiceObject("Service.Location", "ILocation");

                        //override default method implementation
                        pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, opts){
                                function callback(transId, eventCode, result) {
                                    if (eventCode == 4) {
                                        error({message:"Position unavailable", code:2});
                                    } else {
                                        //no timestamp of location given?
                                        success( {  timestamp:null, 
                                                    coords: {
                                                            latitude:   result.ReturnValue.Latitude, 
                                                            longitude:  result.ReturnValue.Longitude, 
                                                            altitude:   result.ReturnValue.Altitude,
                                                            heading:    result.ReturnValue.Heading }
                                                });
                                    }
                                }
                        //location criteria

                        var criteria = new Object();
                        criteria.LocationInformationClass = "BasicLocationInformation";
                        //make the call
                        provider.ILocation.GetLocation(criteria,callback);
                        }
                } else  {                            
                        pub.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error, opts) {
                                pub.jsonp.fetch(ipGeolocationSrv, 
                                        function( p ){ success( { timestamp: p.timestamp, 
                                                                   coords: { 
                                                                        latitude:   p.latitude, 
                                                                        longitude:  p.longitude,
                                                                        heading:    p.heading
                                                                    }
                                                                });});
                        }
                        provider = true;
                }
            }
            catch (e){ 
                if( typeof(console) != u ) console.log(e);                  
                return false;
            }
            return  provider!=null;
        }
        return pub;
      }();
```

In Internet explorer works correctly for me, but when I try it on Google Chrome it shows me the location of another city near my region. I'd like to be able to solve it, and let me show my correct location in google chrome.

I noticed that in internet explorer it takes a few seconds more to load to visualize the location, perhaps in the google chrome lacks some pre-load cleaning or some compatibility.

In Internet Explorer it is right:
[image]

but in google chrome the location shows me wrong:
[image]

My objective is to be able to obtain my location with the map in an exact way in different browsers with javascript or some type code on the client side.

If anyone knows, of course, I appreciate your attention.

Comment: did you enable access in chrome browser ?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Comment: you access the map through http or https ?

Comment: place this on your page and try pls 

preventDefault();

Comment: @AhmedShahin I access through http, in which part I would place preventDefault ()

Comment: @AhmedShahin - where would one put that random code that will fail because `preventDefault` is an **event** method, not just some function you can call at random?

Comment: ok your problem is that accessing the map from http , well , loads of things been changed on chrome since august 2018 , i asked you to write this to find out if there is anything conflicting any other events during detection on you page  

accessing google map is not allowed through http any more .. did you know that ?

Comment: on page load , but for sure the problem is http i know that cus i been there before

Comment: This works in IE11 because IE11 is old and hasn't been touched in years. Real browsers no longer allow geolocation functions to operate on insecure web pages

Comment: you're close @AhmedShahin - but you're wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX I think you're right, since it does not give me the exact location in mozilla either. Make the change using Jquery's document ready by calling the functions from there, but it's still the same

Comment: @CarmenCisternaChamblas - the sole issue is that you are hosting the page using `http` rather than `https` - I'm assuming you **do** have a google maps API key, because the maps as of about a month ago would stop working altogether for all browsers - and that isn't the case at all. So, yes, you'll need to use `https` - letsencrypt is a free SSL certificate authority ... free ...

Comment: FYI: you are using a package of which the last commit was on 24 Mar 2013.

I don't know any newest fork.